# Install fonts in Guix System

Tags: software-installation, fonts, guix

How do I install a font in Guix System? (Not installed in graphical environment)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Search for fonts (using `recutils` to filter results , only name will be displayed):

```
guix package -s font |recsel -p name
```

You can add a short discription for the results:

```
guix package -s font |recsel -p name,synopsis
```

Then install the desired fonts. e,g:

```
guix package -i font-dejavu
```

update fontconfig cache:

```
guix package -i fontconfig
fc-cache -rv
```

For `ttf/otf` : `guix package -s ttf` or `guix package -s font |grep ttf`:

```
guix package -i font-gnu-freefont
```

To install the local font file, drop the font or folder with the font in (`~/.local/share/fonts`). If the `fonts` folder does not exist, create it!